# Liquid: if statement inside raw

Tags: shopify, liquid

i have this if-statement inside a raw-block:

```
{{#if this}}
  <span class="ajaxcart__product-meta">{{@key}}: {{this}}</span>
{{/if}}
```

I need to change the if-statement that its only true when thes is equal to "ImageCode".  Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a

```
{{#if this }}
```

Why can you not just test your condition there?

```
{{#if this == "ImageCode" }}
```

Why is that so hard?

Comment: I tried that dor sure. It results in an error inside a raw-block

Comment: It looks like pretty simple Handlebars JS to me. Without you posting more code, no one can help you. You should show ALL your relevant code too, not the junk, but enough to show off the real issues. Plus, there is Raw is Liquid and Raw in Handlebars. I use templates all the time in Shopify Liquid, I know they work, but it can take some practice to get it right.